# Chrome localStorage gets erased after a couple of days

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project for a client. My client needs an option to authenticate different devices. My idea was to generate a key and store it in local storage and compare it on the serverside if someone logs in. It doesnt have to be super secure, my client just doesnt want employees to use the app at home etc. I implemented that and it worked fine, but for some reasen local storage gets erased after couple of days. On every device (most devices have chrome set as default browser). I have no idea why that is happening. I only use localStorage.setItem an localStorage.getItem thats it. And still after a week or so the local storage is empty. I searched for answers but everything I found says that local storage gets cleared only by the user.

Comment: Is there some other app on same domain that might be clearing it?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Have used localStorage for years and never run into such an issue. Any common browser extension installed on all these that might be responsible? Not sure why an extension would even clear it...but worth asking

Comment: So you are detecting those problems in Chrome, is that right? On which kind of devices (smarthone, desktop PC etc.)? You should do some investigation with different browsers and devices, maybe you can see something striking. If it's the same for all browsers and devices there's probably sth. wrong in your code. If it's only in one browser the problem could be caused by an extension.